# Error - magick/ImageMagick.h: No such file or directory

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to install driver for fingerprint sensor from source. I have already ran `sudo ./configure` and it doesn't give any error. Then while trying to do `sudo make` I run into the following error.

```
uname@computer:~/libfprint-0.0.6$ sudo make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nirmal/libfprint-0.0.6'
Making all in libfprint
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nirmal/libfprint-0.0.6/libfprint'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -fvisibility=hidden -I./nbis/include  -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7  -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -Wall -Wundef -Wunused -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-pointer-sign -Wshadow -g -O2 -MT libfprint_la-imgdev.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libfprint_la-imgdev.Tpo -c -o libfprint_la-imgdev.lo `test -f 'imgdev.c' || echo './'`imgdev.c
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -fvisibility=hidden -I./nbis/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7 -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline -Wall -Wundef -Wunused -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-pointer-sign -Wshadow -g -O2 -MT libfprint_la-imgdev.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libfprint_la-imgdev.Tpo -c imgdev.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libfprint_la-imgdev.o
imgdev.c:23:32: fatal error: magick/ImageMagick.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:456: recipe for target 'libfprint_la-imgdev.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [libfprint_la-imgdev.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nirmal/libfprint-0.0.6/libfprint'
Makefile:304: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nirmal/libfprint-0.0.6'
Makefile:215: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have already installed following libraries to avoid the 'ImageMagick.h not found error' but still can't get rid of this error:

- graphicsmagick
- graphicsmagick-dbg
- graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
- graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat
- imagemagick-6.q16
- imagemagick-7.0.8
- imagemagick-common
- imagemagick-dbg
- imagemagick-doc
- libgraphics-magick-perl
- libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12
- libgraphicsmagick++1-dev
- libgraphicsmagick-q16-3
- libgraphicsmagick1-dev
- libmage-magick-q16-perl
- libmagick++-6-headers
- libmagick++-6.q16-5v5
- libmagick++-6.q16-dev
- libmagickcore-6-arch-config
- libmagickcore-6.q16-2
- libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra
- libmagickcore-6.q16-dev
- libmagickwand-6-headers
- libmagickwand-6.q16-2
- libmagickwand-6.q16-dev
- libmagickwand-dev

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the file `ImageMagick.h` on your computer?

Comment: Check with `find "$HOME" /usr /opt / -type f -name ImageMagick.h 2> /dev/null`

Comment: What Imagemagick version have you installed? It looks like you need version 7

Comment: You need to **uninstall** ImageMagick-7, and try again.

Comment: I uninstalled all imagemagick libraries and then installed libmagick++-6.q16-dev. The problem is solved, although I don't know what solved it. Thanks for the suggestion to uninstall...